# Systems of equations word problem

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

A goldsmith has two alloys, the first containing $77\%$ and the second containing $96\%$. If $x$ grams of the first alloy are mixed with $y$ grams of the second, obtaining $100$ grams of an alloy which contains $85.93\%$ gold, find $x$ to the nearest gram.

$x=53,y=47$

I don't know where to begin at all.

Comment: Well $x + y = 100$, for starters.

Comment: I understand that, but I meant where does the 77% and 96% come in?

Comment: The $77\%$ and $96\%$ are referring to the percentage of gold, correct?

Comment: The amount of gold is $85.93$g. This equals the amount of gold from the first alloy, which is $.77x$, plus the amount from the second alloy, $.96$y.